# AngularJS - directive for only numbers with decimal places

Tags: angularjs

I would like to create directive for writing only numbers with decimal places. I have this code:

```
zpc. directive('onlyNumbers', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
        modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (inputValue) {
          if (inputValue == undefined) return '';
          var transformedInput = inputValue.replace(/^[0-9](,[0-9]{0,2})?/g, '');
          if (transformedInput !== inputValue) {
            modelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
            modelCtrl.$render();
          }
          return transformedInput;
        });
      }
    };
});
```

I can write numbers with decimal places but other characters too.
Thanks for advices

Comment: you can try angular-ui-mask library which has so many different features for input mask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `ng-pattern` directive, set regular expression.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="onlyNumbers" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*$/">
```

Answer (score 2):

```
angular.directive('decimalPlaces',function(){
  return {
      link:function(scope,ele,attrs){
          ele.bind('keypress',function(e){
              var newVal=$(this).val()+(e.charCode!==0?String.fromCharCode(e.charCode):'');
              if($(this).val().search(/(.*)\.[0-9][0-9]/)===0 && newVal.length>$(this).val().length){
                  e.preventDefault();
              }
          });
      }
  };
});


<input  type="number" step="0.01" ng-model='somemodel' decimal-places>
```

You can also used https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-input-masks.

Hopefully this will help.